# latex -page layout problem

Tags: page, layout

[image]

First of all sorry for my broken english. But i didn't figure out why this happened . thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would guess that are using a document class that has different margins for the left and right hand pages (so by adjusting your margins you can "fix" this issue) but without seeing your code it is impossible to tell if this is the problem and to suggest the best way to fix this. Perhaps, these are even the margins that you actually want? Please consider adding a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to your question.

Comment: You are probably using a documentclass that creates double-sided documents. Maybe [this link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Single_sided_and_double_sided_documents) explains it.